# Project structure is not opening in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

src folder is missing in my currently running android studio project.Project structure is also not opening

`Files->project` structure is in disabled state

in `app-> build`, I can see only 
1)generated 
2)intermediates

but src folder is missing

What might be the reason and how to proceed further?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It means the project source files are missing or Gradle is not able to import all of your project. I suggest you check your hard drive location where the project is located and go through the directories to see if it matches that for default android projects.

Comment: Do you get any errors? Did you try "make project"? Can you create a new project in android studio without issues?